# How to get rss feeds programmatically?

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2012, rss

I want to get rss feeds from multiple sources and store into the list. Is there anyway to get rss feeds from specified urls and store them in to the list? Please provide reference links or code example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is really simple. The best way is creating an External list using Visual Studio.

Here is a service class I wrote.

```
public partial class BlogArticleService
{
    private const string FeedUrl = "http://blogs.microsoft.com/feed/";

    private const string DateDisplayFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy";

    private static List<BlogArticle> blogArticles = new List<BlogArticle>();

    public static IEnumerable<BlogArticle> ReadList()
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(BlogArticleService.FeedUrl);
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();

        blogArticles = new List<BlogArticle>();

        int id=0;
        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            BlogArticle currentArticle = new BlogArticle();
            currentArticle.ID = id;
            currentArticle.Title = item.Title.Text;
            currentArticle.LinkToArticle = item.Links[0].Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            currentArticle.PublishedDate = item.PublishDate.Date.ToString(BlogArticleService.DateDisplayFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            blogArticles.Add(currentArticle);
            id++;
        }

        return blogArticles;
    }

    public static BlogArticle ReadItem(int iD)
    {
        return blogArticles.Where(m => m.ID == iD).First();
    }
}
```

My blog has much resources. [Here](http://www.malindesilva.net/2014/07/sharepoint-2013-external-list.html) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no direct mechanism in SharePoint to import the content of RSS feeds into a list. The simplest solution would be to write a custom Timer Job that grabs the RSS feed and populates the list.

The RSS feed can, for example, be read with the [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class or a custom reader. RSS is - after all - only XML...

Comment: Can you provide any code sample that shows how to deal with SyndicationFeed to fetch web parts?

Comment: Sorry. I don't have any code for this approach ready. But why want you fetch web parts? In the question you mentioned RSS feeds...

Comment: I needed to provide a web part that displays rss feeds from multiple Site's rss feed. To do that, I planned to make list that stores the feeds from sites and develop a visual web part and display those feeds in that.

Comment: If all data is stored in SharePoint itself, another solution might be a search driven approach where you use SharePoint search to aggregate the result.

Comment: Yes, but my requirement is that the end users will enter the as number of Rss urls as they want and I have to display the related rss feeds.